# matplotlib break line near a marker

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

Is there are posibility to break a line in a matplotlib diagram. I made a sketch for better understanding what I mean. [image]

Comment: I don't understand the question. What do you mean by 'intercept'? Are you talking about the gaps around your points? If not, what kind of output are you expecting? What code have you written? Did you try adding white edges to your markers? Read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Sorry but english is not my mother tungue. intercept is the wrong word.

Comment: No worries, see if I interpreted it correctly -- maybe 'offset' or 'gap' or something like that. Especially in a linear plot, I would take 'intercept' to mean 'intersection', especially of the line with the y-axis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by 'intercept' you mean the gaps or buffers between the points and the lines, I'd add an edge around the points like so:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = y = [1, 2, 3]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, y, lw=5, c='k')  # The black line.
ax.scatter(x, y, s=200, c='lime', ec='white', lw=5, zorder=10)
ax.set_xlim(0.5, 3.5)
ax.set_ylim(0.5, 3.5)
```

This prodices:

[image: resulting plot]

I'm plotting the line and points separately, controlling the layer order with `zorder`. There are always lots of ways to do things, but I find markers easier to control with [`plt.scatter()`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.scatter.html).